# Higher order derivative of parameter curves

Tags: calculus

Given 
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
x &= f(t)\\
y &= g(t)
\end{align*}\right.
$$

We can compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$ simply by
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{g'(t)}{f '(t)}
$$

However when I tried to compute $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, I met some problem. I've tried the chain rule but it seemed failed.

Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$, and $\frac{d}{dx}(\cdots)=\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{d}{dt}(\cdots)$

Comment: Are you sure that the derivatives you want are really $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ and not $\frac{d^n(x,y)}{dt^n}$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes.

Comment: [Parametric derivatives](http://calculusapplets.com/parametric.html)

Comment: This question is similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/68988/) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/49734/). Do you have a question not answered by one of their answers?

Comment: $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y}-\dot{y}\ddot{x}}{\dot{x}^{3}}$$ , where $\dot{x}=x'_t$ and $\ddot{x}=x''_t$

Comment: @robjohn: Ah..I'm very sorry that I forgot to search before asking after a long time not using this site... Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set $y'={dy\over dx}$, then $${d\over dt} y'={dy'\over dx}{dx\over dt};$$
whence $${d^2y\over dx^2}={ {dy' / dt} \over {dx/dt}}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried to apply '$\frac{d}{dx}$' and did not see that applying '$\frac{d}{dt}$' first then we can solve '$\frac{d}{dx}$' out.