# A general formula for $(\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds})^k$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

## Background

A sub-problem of some velocity planning problems is to determine the velocity curve where for some k:
$$
\frac{d^kv}{dt^k}=\text{constant}\tag{1}
$$
However, the velocity should be solved in the form $v=v(s)$, rather than $v=v(t)$. Where $s$ is the arc length, so that
$$
\frac{ds}{dt}=v\tag{2}
$$

Therefore we have a change-of-variable problem for an ODE.

## The Problem

Given ODE (1) and (2), I want to transform equation (1) from an equation of v(t) to an equation of v(s).

Here is what I have tried:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^kv}{dt^k}&=(\frac{d}{dt})^kv\\
                 &=(\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds})^kv
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, it is natural to consider a general formula for $(\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds})^k$.

I've calculated formulas for the first few values of k:
$$
(\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds})^2=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\frac{d}{ds}+(\frac{ds}{dt})^2\frac{d^2}{ds^2}
$$
$$
(\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds})^3=\frac{d^3s}{dt^3}\frac{d}{ds}+3\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d^s}{dt^2}\frac{d^2}{ds^2}+(\frac{ds}{dt})^3\frac{d^3}{ds^3}
$$

These formulas looks a little like Equation (11) to (13) in [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DifferentialOperator.html).
And I've also seen [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68988/a-general-formula-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-a-parametrically-defined-function) on stackexchange.

These are similar problems, but they have different answers. And one answer seems not giving me an insight for another.

Is there a general formula for my problem? Is there a general method for these problems? BTW, is there a software which can calculate these formulas automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) can help you. See also [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_derivatives).

Comment: Ah..That is exactly what I want. Thank you!